# Windows Form not connect to Syncfusion packages in release mode

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I have created a windows form application to generate a pdf. When I am in debug mode and run the application, it works and generates the pdf from gridview data. When I tried to publish the application to my computer as a desktop app it runs but when I click to generate the pdf from the gridview data It pops up an exception error.
[This is an image of the exception that is thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJFvZ.png)

I have multiple .dll files in my bin folder but I'm not sure which one is most important for a release. Let me know if there is anything more needed to help.

Comment: Did you actually read the information provided? It's telling you that it can't find a file and the stack trace makes it pretty clear where in the code it's looking for a file: the one you're passing to the `PdfBitmap` constructor in the `Click` event handler for `button1`. You need to work out what path it's looking for and that should tell you why it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the reported exception “FileNotFoundException: File can’t be found” exception occurs when the input image files are not present in the release folder. Please make sure the release bin folder contains those image files. If it is not present, please include the file's path and provide the common folder path to get the files for running the application in both debug and release mode.